# Show terminal command output in new editor window in VSCode

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

Some terminal commands generate a huge number of logs but the terminal truncates it so I can't see the complete command output. Is there a way to pipe the complete command output to a new Untitled tab in the editor instead?

I can do it in 2 steps, first, redirect output to a file and then open that file in the VSCode. but is there a shorter way/one-liner :)

Comment: What’s wrong with the solution you posted? Isn’t that already really short? What does it matter that your solution is two lines, instead of one? Don’t answer here; update your question.

Comment: any solution for above question